# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException crashes application

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, exception, rss

This application, [RomeCNN](https://github.com/THUFIR/RomeCNN), uses [Rome 1.5.0](http://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/index.html) to iterate through a CNN news feed and persist the URL's to a database.  The database rejects duplicate links.

That there are `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` type exceptions is ok, those inserts should get rejected by the database.  Perhaps there's a better way to avoid duplicates, but for now this is sufficient.  (Unless something else is happening?  I was thinking "if the link already exists, catch the exception, and move on to the next".)

Why does the application crash?  After a certain threshold of integrity constraint violations, the connection is broken?

```
run:
     [java] [EL Info]: 2014-11-03 01:20:39.432--ServerSession(28432534)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
     [java] [EL Info]: connection: 2014-11-03 01:20:40.173--ServerSession(28432534)--file:/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/RomeCNN/build/classes/_RomeReaderPU login successful
     [java] [EL Warning]: 2014-11-03 01:20:40.405--UnitOfWork(6261946)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
     [java] Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/WD5Aw61It7M/nr-kenya' for key 'UNQ_links_0'
     [java] Error Code: 1062
     [java] Call: INSERT INTO links.links (created, link, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
     [java]     bind => [3 parameters bound]
     [java] Query: InsertObjectQuery(romereader.Link[ id=null ])
     [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
     [java] Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/WD5Aw61It7M/nr-kenya' for key 'UNQ_links_0'
     [java] Error Code: 1062
     [java] Call: INSERT INTO links.links (created, link, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
     [java]     bind => [3 parameters bound]
     [java] Query: InsertObjectQuery(romereader.Link[ id=null ])
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
     [java]     at romereader.LinkJpaController.create(LinkJpaController.java:31)
     [java]     at romereader.Main.getLinks(Main.java:41)
     [java]     at romereader.Main.main(Main.java:21)
     [java] Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
     [java] Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/WD5Aw61It7M/nr-kenya' for key 'UNQ_links_0'
     [java] Error Code: 1062
     [java] Call: INSERT INTO links.links (created, link, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
     [java]     bind => [3 parameters bound]
     [java] Query: InsertObjectQuery(romereader.Link[ id=null ])
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/WD5Aw61It7M/nr-kenya' for key 'UNQ_links_0'
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
     [java]     ... 34 more
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/RomeCNN$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/RomeCNN$
```

The JpaController:

```
package romereader;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import romereader.exceptions.NonexistentEntityException;


public class LinkJpaController implements Serializable {

    public LinkJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(Link link) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(link);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(Link link) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            link = em.merge(link);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                Integer id = link.getId();
                if (findLink(id) == null) {
                    throw new NonexistentEntityException("The link with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy(Integer id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Link link;
            try {
                link = em.getReference(Link.class, id);
                link.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The link with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(link);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Link> findLinkEntities() {
        return findLinkEntities(true, -1, -1);
    }

    public List<Link> findLinkEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        return findLinkEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
    }

    private List<Link> findLinkEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Link.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public Link findLink(Integer id) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(Link.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public int getLinkCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<Link> rt = cq.from(Link.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
```

While inserts are made to the database, why it chokes, apparently, on either constraints violations, or a specific URL, isn't clear to me.

the `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RomeReaderPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>romereader.Links</class>
    <class>romereader.Link</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/links?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jdbc"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to first check if the link exists in the database and then either update/skip or insert new item. Basically something like this:

```
em = getEntityManager();
Link existing = em.find(Link.class, link.getLink());
if (existing == null) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(link);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

To make this maybe more robust, I would use [SyndEntry.getUri()](https://github.com/rometools/rome/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rometools/rome/feed/synd/SyndEntry.java) value as unique identifier. I can't check now, but I'm sure it maps to the `guid` element of an item:

```
<item>
<title>Protectionist wins Melbourne Cup</title>
<guid>http://edition.cnn.com/2014/11/04/asia/gallery/melbourne-cup/index.html</guid>
<link>http://edition.cnn.com/2014/11/04/asia/gallery/melbourne-cup/index.html?eref=edition</link>
<description>Australia's Melbourne Cup</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 04 Nov 2014 01:52:42 EST</pubDate>
</item>
```

If you choose to update elements, then the [pubDate](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltpubdategtSubelementOfLtitemgt) value can be used to determine if the item has been updated since the last time you saved it.

[RSS Duplicate Detection](http://web.archive.org/web/20140414063142/http://www.xn--8ws00zhy3a.com/blog/2006/08/rss-dup-detection) is an intresting blog post about this subject (unfortunately only currently found via archive.org.)

If you read the [RSS 2.0 specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), you'll find that `<link>` can be omitted from `<item>` so that can also be good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the create method as so:

```
public void create(Link link) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(link);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.fine(e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

which seems absurd.  However, as it runs now without crashing, I suppose it's a solution.  Better solutions would be welcome.  Perhaps there's a flaw in the general approach.